# `require': cannot load such file -- curses (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a ruby beginner and trying to understand and learn ruby. I came across this error while trying to run a ruby file which uses "require curses" but I am getting the following error while doing so. Any help or hint is appreciated.

```
desktop$ ruby curses.rb 
/desktop/jsipp-master$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
curses (1.2.4)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
enumerate (0.0.7)
enumerated (1.0.1)
enumeration (1.3.3)
ffi (1.9.25)
ffi-rzmq (2.0.6)
ffi-rzmq-core (1.0.6)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
libxml-ruby (2.9.0)
minitest (5.8.5)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.1.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
test-unit (3.1.5)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- curses (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from curses.rb:3:in `<main>'

   jsipp-master$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'curses'
require 'ffi-rzmq'
require 'enumerator'

POSITIONS = "%15s %8s %8s %12s %12s %12s\n"
POSITIONS2 = "%-38s %-38s\n"
POSITIONS3 = "%15s %-12s%%-10s%%-10s%%-10s%%-15s\n"

OUT_ARROW = "-------->"
IN_ARROW = "<--------"
PAUSE =    "[%6dms]"

class MinuteLongBuffer
  def initialize
    @values = []
  end

  def add v
    @values << [Time.new.to_f, v]
  end

  def count
    @values = @values.keep_if {|v| v[0] > (Time.new.to_f - 1)}
    @values.length
  end
end

class Scenario
  def parse_scenario_desc desc
    @strings = []
    @msg_counts = []
    parts = desc.split(";")
    parts.each do |part|
      type, value = part.split(":")
      if type == "IN"
        @strings << (POSITIONS3 % [value, IN_ARROW])
      elsif type == "OUT"
        @strings << (POSITIONS3 % [value, OUT_ARROW])
      elsif type == "PAUSE"
        @strings << (POSITIONS3 % [(PAUSE % value), ""])
      end
      @msg_counts << 0
      @unexpected_msg_counts << 0
      @timeout_counts << 0
    end
  end

  def inc_msg idx
    @msg_counts[idx.to_i] += 1
    if idx.to_i == 0
      @new_calls.add 1
    end
  end

  def inc_unexpected idx
    @unexpected_msg_counts[idx.to_i] += 1
  end

  def inc_timeout idx
    @timeout_counts[idx.to_i] += 1
  end

  def update
    Curses.clear
    Curses.addstr(POSITIONS % ["Call-rate", "Length", "Port", "Total-time", "Total-calls", "Remote-host"])
    Curses.addstr(POSITIONS % [("?cps"), "? ms", "????", ("%.2fs" % (Time.new.to_f - @start)), "?", "??? (???)"])
    Curses.addstr("\n")
    Curses.addstr(POSITIONS2 % ["%d new calls during 1.000s period" % @new_calls.count, "?ms scheduler resolution"])
    Curses.addstr(POSITIONS2 % ["? concurrent calls (limit ?)", "Peak was ? calls, after ?s"])
    Curses.addstr(POSITIONS2 % ["? out-of-call msg (discarded)", "? open sockets"])
    Curses.addstr("\n")
    Curses.addstr((POSITIONS3 % ["", "",]) % ["Messages", "Retrans", "Timeout", "Unexpected-Msg"])
    @strings.each_with_index do |s, i|
      Curses.addstr(s % [@msg_counts[i], 0, @timeout_counts[i], @unexpected_msg_counts[i]])
    end
    Curses.refresh
  end

  def initialize
    @new_calls = MinuteLongBuffer.new
    @strings = []
    @msg_counts = []
    @unexpected_msg_counts = []
    @timeout_counts = []
    @start = Time.new.to_f

    Thread.new do
      context = ZMQ::Context.new
      socket = context.socket(ZMQ::SUB)
      socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")
      socket.setsockopt(ZMQ::SUBSCRIBE, "SIPP")

      socket2 = context.socket(ZMQ::REQ)
      socket2.connect("tcp://localhost:5557")
      socket2.send_string "",0
      socket2.recv_string msg2 = ""
      parse_scenario_desc msg2
      loop do
        socket.recv_strings(msgs = [])
        msgs.each do |msg|
        name, ts, scenario, callnum, callid, idx, result = msg.split(":")
        if name == "SIPP-PHASE_SUCCESS"
          inc_msg idx
        end
        if name == "SIPP-UNEXPECTED_MSG_RECVD"
          inc_unexpected idx
        end
        if name == "SIPP-RECV_TIMED_OUT"
          inc_timeout idx
        end
      end
      end
    end
  end
end

SCENARIO = Scenario.new

Curses.init_screen()

Thread.new do
  loop do
    tmp = Curses.getch
  end
end

loop do
  SCENARIO.update
  sleep 1
end
```

Also when I check the ruby version it is pointing to 2.3.3 but while running the it shows me ruby 2.3.0 running the file. If someone could explain why is that would also help me.
After installing gems in file manually I am getting another error please see below.

```
/jsipp-master$ ruby curses.rb
Unable to load this gem. The libzmq library (or DLL) could not be found.
If this is a Windows platform, make sure libzmq.dll is on the PATH.
If the DLL was built with mingw, make sure the other two dependent DLLs,
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll and libstdc++6.dll, are also on the PATH.
For non-Windows platforms, make sure libzmq is located in this search path:
["/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/../../ext/libzmq.dylib", "/usr/local/bin/libzmq.dylib", "/usr/bin/libzmq.dylib", "/bin/libzmq.dylib", "/usr/sbin/libzmq.dylib", "/sbin/libzmq.dylib", "/opt/X11/bin/libzmq.dylib", "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libzmq.dylib", "/usr/local/lib/libzmq.dylib", "/opt/local/lib/libzmq.dylib", "/usr/local/lib/libzmq.dylib", "/usr/lib64/libzmq.dylib"]
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/libzmq.rb:61:in `rescue in <module:LibZMQ>': The libzmq library (or DLL) could not be loaded (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/libzmq.rb:10:in `<module:LibZMQ>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/libzmq.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq-core.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-2.0.6/lib/ffi-rzmq.rb:66:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from curses.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please add more details: paste the content of the ruby file, and/or the the content of Gemfile if you have one. Please also paste the result of the command `gem list | grep curses`

Comment: @jedi thanks for reaching out I have updated my issue further please take a look and provide some suggestions thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you have not installed the `curses` gem.

You can check to see if it is installed using the `gem list` command.  If your gem is not listed, it isn't installed:

```
$ gem list curses

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

$
```

If it is not installed, install the gem using the `gem install` command:

```
$ gem install curses
Fetching: curses-1.2.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed curses-1.2.4
Parsing documentation for curses-1.2.4
Installing ri documentation for curses-1.2.4
Done installing documentation for curses after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$
```

You can read more in [the online gem command reference](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/).

That should get you beyond the error you are seeing.